# Codeigniter - Grab value from dropdown pass to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass a value from a form which has 3 options so when the user clicks on any of the options it should pass the value to the controller.

I am thinking maybe i can have something like `onChange="selectedValue". I tried to grab the post from the view but it did not work.

Any help would be appreciated

View

```
            <label>Reports</label>
            <form>
            <select NAME="hours">
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>

            </select>
            </form>
```

Controller

```
public function about()
{
    $search = $this->input->post('hours');

    echo $search;

    $this->load->view("about");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd normally pass a value from a view to a controller, by sumitting the form in the view to a function in a controller. You can add JavaScript to the form to automatically submit it when an option is selected - `onchange="this.form.submit()"`. (Rather than using a button, for example.)

**View**

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?php echo site_url("yourcontroller/about"); ?>">
    <select name="hours" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function about()
{
    //Get the value from the form.
    $search = $this->input->post('hours');

    //Put the value in an array to pass to the view. 
    $view_data['search'] = $search;

    //Pass to the value to the view. Access it as '$search' in the view.
    $this->load->view("about", $view_data);
}
```

Comment: using $this->input->post('hours'); we can get value of drop down if we want to get text then what we have to do